# Implicit, static type cast (coercion) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, casting, type-conversion, ghc, typeclass

### Problem

Consider the following design problem in Haskell. I have a simple, symbolic EDSL in which I want to express variables and general expressions (multivariate polynomials) such as `x^2 * y + 2*z + 1`. In addition, I want to express certain symbolic equations over expressions, say `x^2 + 1 = 1`, as well as *definitions*, like `x := 2*y - 2`.

The goal is to:

1. Have a separate type for variables and general expressions - certain
   functions might be applied to variables and not complex expressions.
   For instance, a *definition* operator `:=` might be of type
   `(:=) :: Variable -> Expression -> Definition` and it should not
   be possible to pass a complex expression as its left-hand side
   parameter (though it *should* be possible to pass a variable as its
   right-hand side parameter, **without explicit casting**).
2. Have expressions an instance of `Num`, so that it's possible to
   promote integer literals to expressions and use a convenient
   notation for common algebraic operations like addition or
   multiplication without introducing some auxiliary wrapper operators.

In other words, I would like to have an *implicit* and *static* type cast (coercion) of variables to expressions. Now, I know that as such, there are no implicit type casts in Haskell. Nevertheless, certain object-oriented programming concepts (simple inheritance, in this case) are *expressible* in Haskell's type system, either with or without language extensions. How could I satisfy both above points while keeping a lightweight syntax? Is it even possible?

### Discussion

It is clear that the main problem here is `Num`'s type restriction, e.g.

`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`

In principle, it's possible to write a single (generalised) algebraic data type for both variables and expressions. Then, one could write `:=` in such a way, that the left-hand side expression is discriminated and only a variable constructor is accepted, with a run-time error otherwise. That's however not a clean, static (i.e. compile-time) solution...

### Example

Ideally, I would like to achieve a lightweight syntax such as

```
computation = do
  x <- variable
  t <- variable

  t |:=| x^2 - 1
  solve (t |==| 0)
```

In particular, I want to forbid notation like
`t + 1 |:=| x^2 - 1` since `:=` should give a definition of a variable and not an entire left-hand side expression.

Comment: maybe you could use a `class FromVar e` with a method `fromVar :: Variable -> e` and provide instances for `Expression` and `Variable`, then have your variables have polymorphic types `x :: FromVar e => e` etc. I haven't tested how well this works since I'm on my phone right now.

Comment: I am not sure how the ```FromVar``` typeclass would be of help. I want to avoid explicit casts while keeping ```Expr``` an instance of ```Num```. I edited the question adding an example of a notation I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To leverage polymorphism rather than subtyping (because that's all you have in Haskell), don't think "a variable is an expression", but "both variables and expressions have some operations in common". Those operations can be put in a type class:

```hs
class HasVar e where fromVar :: Variable -> e

instance HasVar Variable where fromVar = id
instance HasVar Expression where ...
```

Then, rather than casting things, make things polymorphic. If you have `v :: forall e. HasVar e => e`, it can be used both as an expression and as a variable.

```hs
example :: (forall e. HasVar e => e) -> Definition
example v = (v := v)  -- v can be used as both Variable and Expression

 where

  (:=) :: Variable -> Expression -> Definition
```

Skeleton to make the code below typecheck: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/da30abac357deb7981412f1faf0d2103

```hs
computation :: Solver ()
computation = do
  V x <- variable
  V t <- variable
  t |:=| x^2 - 1
  solve (t |==| 0)
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I considered hiding both variables and expressions behind existential types for a brief moment, however I rejected the idea because it introduced additional notation, see your ```V```. Initially that's not what I wanted, but perhaps I was too quick to dismiss it... Probably I cannot get rid of the opaque ```V```. On a related note, how can I create an instance of ```V (forall e . HasVar e => e)```? In Coq, I would use type computations and pattern matching on an inductive type, but it's unclear how to achieve that in Haskell.

Comment: You can grab a `w :: Variable` somehow and apply `fromVar` to it: `variable = (\w -> V (fromVar w)) <$> (_TODO_ :: Solver Variable)`.

Comment: And `V` could be avoided with impredicative types, but that's still WIP. Or we can make `variable` take the continuation with a polymorphic argument explicitly instead of indirectly via `(>>=)`.